# Adding elements to a list in python

Tags: python, json, list

I have the following list - `params`

```
params
[{'vehicles': [{'images': [], 'id': 55}], 'dealerId': 12345}]
>>> type(params)
<type 'list'>
```

My requirement is to add two more elements to the 'images' element, namely `imageId` and `imageUrl`

```
[
{
"dealerId":12345,
"vehicles":[
        {
        "id": 55,
        "images" : [
            {
            "imageId": 91,
            "imageUrl":"file://image1.jpg"
            },
            {
            "imageId": 92,
            "imageUrl":"file://image2.jpg"
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
}
]
```

I would really appreciate any help.

**NOTE: `params` is of list type and not json**

Comment: Can your list contain multiple elements to update? And have you tried something?

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? What have you actually tried? SO is not a free coding service after all.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I know i should have been more detailed. Sorry for that but I didn’t have much time for that. You can find the answer to your question in the comment section of the answer below. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
images = params[0]["vehicles"]["images"]
images.append({
        "imageId": 91,
        "imageUrl":"file://image1.jpg"
    })
images.append({
        "imageId": 92,
        "imageUrl":"file://image2.jpg"
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just access the images list, then append the dictionary with the info you want.

```
params[0]["vehicles"][0]["images"].append({"imageId":91, "imageUrl":"file://image1.jpg"})
```

To reach this solution, think about your list, params. You want to edit the list associated with the key "images".

```
# Gives the first dictionary containing the keys "vehicles" and "dealerId"
params[0]

# Gives the list containing the dictionary containing the keys "images" and "id"
params[0]["vehicles"]

# Gives the dictionary containing the keys "images" and "id"
params[0]["vehicles"][0]

# Gives the list associated with the key "images"
params[0]["vehicles"][0]["images"]
```

Once reaching the correct list, you can append/edit as desired.

Comment: Thanks @ndlawrence. I was doing the same thing but without using the string "vehicles". Instead I was just using the index number.